# WPF UI performance impact when loading images

Tags: c#, wpf, image, data-binding, .net-4.8

I have been looking into ways to minimize the performance impact on binding/loading images to a list.

I have tried a few different options that people suggest online, such as:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fc238ea-194e-4f29-bcbd-9a3d4bdb2180/async-loading-of-bitmapsource-in-value-converter?forum=wpf

or using a separate thread to load the list of Images into ImageSource then bind to the list view

and/or priority binding with the main source marked as async (i didn't see any improvement when I use this approach alone, tbh)

they all have some level of improvement and I ended up with something like the following:
a custom Image control with async loading

```
public class AsyncImage : Image
{
    private static ImageSource _blank;
    private static Random random;
    private static ImageSource Blank 
    {
        get
        {
            if(_blank == null)
            {
                var bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                Stream imgStream = File.OpenRead("D:\\...\\blankLoading.png");
                bi.StreamSource = imgStream;
                bi.EndInit();
                bi.Freeze();
                _blank = bi;
            }
            return _blank;
        }
    }
    public string ImageUrl
    {
        get { return GetValue(ImageUrlProperty).ToString(); }
        set 
        { 
            SetValue(ImageUrlProperty, value);
            LoadImageAsync(value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageUrlProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ImageUrl", typeof(string), typeof(AsyncImage), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnImageUrlChanged)));

    private static void OnImageUrlChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AsyncImage control = (AsyncImage)d;
        control.ImageUrl = e.NewValue.ToString();
    }
    private void LoadImageAsync(string url)
    {
        Image image = new Image();
        base.Source = Blank; 

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((r) =>
        {
          
            BitmapImage bi = null;
            bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(url); //i want to make sure data is loaded before assignment
            bi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            bi.EndInit();
            bi.Freeze(); //makes sure your image can be passed across threads
            Console.Write(url);
            image.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (ThreadStart)delegate
                {
                    base.Source = bi; //this is where it actually comes back to UI thread
                });
        });

    }
}
```

with this approach, I can just bind a list of URLs or file paths to a list view and the data binding will perform a lot smoother... HOWEVER, it always causes a little freeze on the UI when the actual image is been shown (at the last line). the freeze is more noticeable when you have a good list of last images.

Is there a way to solve this issue? all I want is that the UI will still be responsive while images show up...

Comment: Are you properly disposing of resources everywhere in this code? If there happens to be undisposed resources left behind anywhere, then this can become a temporary memory hog that I imagine possibly slows down execution. Just a thought.

Comment: you are right @BentTranberg, good point. i was going to do that once I solve the issue and tidy up the code. wasnt quite sure about my code at this stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code. You must not call `LoadImageAsync()` in the setter of the `ImageUrl` property. The method must instead be called in `OnImageUrlChanged`.

In LoadImageAsync you are creating an Image element only to use its Dispatcher, which is totally pointless. Use the Dispatcher of your custom control, like `this.Dispatcher`. Also write `this.Source` instead of `base.Source`.

You must also close the stream from wich a BitmapImage is loaded. Set `bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` and dispose of the MemoryStream by a `using` block.

That said, consider using a more modern implementation without `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Use `Task.Run` instead:

```
public class AsyncImage : Image
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImagePathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ImagePath), typeof(string), typeof(AsyncImage),
            new PropertyMetadata(async (o, e) =>
                await ((AsyncImage)o).LoadImageAsync((string)e.NewValue)));

    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ImagePathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImagePathProperty, value); }
    }

    private async Task LoadImageAsync(string imagePath)
    {
        Source = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(imagePath))
            {
                var bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bi.StreamSource = stream;
                bi.EndInit();
                bi.Freeze();
                return bi;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out my mistakes and the code, that works a charm... so with the first point you made, was I actually still calling the load on the main thread?

Comment: No, there must simply not be anything else than the SetValue call in the property setter. I assume your performance problem was due to the redundant Image element.

Comment: This is a  good answer.